# Console log return empty array after findzByIdanddelte

Tags: mongodb

I am not why is it returning empty after delete and find when there are still records. here is my code:

```
router.post('/schedule/deleteschedule',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {   
    await Schedule.findByIdAndDelete({_id:req.body.id})
    const scheduleresult = await Schedule.find({userid:req.params.id}).sort({startdate: 1})
    console.log(scheduleresult)
    return res.json(scheduleresult)
    
});
```

The console log returns empty even though I use find but that should not be as I still some records. What am I doing wrong here? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not passing params in routes for params you need to put /:id in the end of route.
One suggestion try to use put for update.

```
 router.post('/schedule/deleteschedule/:id',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {   
    await Schedule.findByIdAndDelete({_id:req.body.id})
    const scheduleresult = await Schedule.find({userid:req.params.id}).sort({startdate: 1})
    console.log(scheduleresult)
    return res.json(scheduleresult)
    
});
```